# Игнорирование папок в GIT по частичному названию

Tags: qt, git

я новичок в GIT, и хотел бы задать вопрос по .gitignore.
Заключается он в следующем. Я работаю с Qt, который генерирует для сборок каталоги с очень длинными названиями, которые содержит и название компилятора, и название проекта, и релиз/дебаг и много чего еще. Каждый раз в ручную вводить или даже копировать эти каталоги в .gitignore не с руки. Но я точно знаю, что во всех названиях для сгенерированных папок есть слово Build. Могу ли я сделать такой шаблон, чтобы он проверял названия всех каталогов в текущем, и если в их названии есть это слово, он их пропускал? Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Почему бы и [да](https://www.atlassian.com/ru/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#git-ignore-patterns)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28765170/14775762